# Zxing Mobile doesn't stop analysing on iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, barcode-scanner, zxing.net

Net.Mobile to implement barcode scanning into an app.

I currently have a little demo app that has implemented a scanning page, I can read barcodes and do something. I'm using Xamarin Forms to implement the barcode scanning. I looked at the sample app provided by ZXing and copied the code for one of their scanners to use in my demo. Now i have tested this app in android, I'm using an API 21 phone and it lags like hell but all in all it works. I can scan a barcode and navigate to a new screen.

When testing on iOS (using an iphone 6 on the latest version - 11.2.5) I noticed that the iphone never stops reading barcodes. Here is the code that get called when the phone recognises a barcode:

```
zxing.OnScanResult += (result) =>
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => {

// Stop analysis until we navigate away so we don't keep reading barcodes
zxing.IsAnalyzing = false;

// Show an alert
await DisplayAlert("Scanned Barcode", result.Text, "OK");

// Navigate away
await Navigation.PushAsync(new ScanResultsPage());

});
```

So as you can see the first thing that gets called when a barcode is recognised is `zxing.IsAnalyzing = false;`, this works on android. However on iOS it continues scanning and if I point the phone at the barcode, more and more alerts get added to the screen. I am new to Xamarin Forms and have never encountered any issues when adding barcodes to iOS natively.

I don't really know where to begin debugging this, I put a breakpoint on this line of code `zxing.IsAnalyzing = false;`, it executes and I can see the value is set to false.

Could this be an issue with the ZXing framework itself?

Thanks

(I have called init in the app delegate)

Answer (score 0):

Refer to  [sample usage](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/zxing.net.mobile.forms)  , I think you should add `scanPage.IsScanning = false;` to stop scanning.

```
scanPage.OnScanResult += (result) => {
// Stop scanning
    scanPage.IsScanning = false;

    // Pop the page and show the result
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() => {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new ScanResultsPage());       
        DisplayAlert("Scanned Barcode", result.Text, "OK");
    });
};
```

Comment: setting scanning to false stops the scanner altogether (disables the camera). In the sample app and in android `scanner.IsAnalyzing = false;` works. It is only in iOS that is doesn't stop scanning...

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. Exactly the same issue, the boolean gets set to false but the code decides to execute anyway. I raised this as an issue on github and will be implementing native iOS scanning (using apples superior frameworks)